# SQL to find set of children with common parents

Tags: sql, db2

In my db2 database I have three tables.

1. Computer
2. Computer_Software
3. Software

This stores the relationship that each computer has multiple software items installed.  So Computer_Software just has a foreign key to Computer and Software.

I need a query that returns for a given set of computers, the list of software which is installed on ALL of them.

So it would be something like this:

```
select id from software where computer_id = 1 
intersect
select id from software where computer_id = 2
intersect 
select id from software where computer_id = 5
```

But I need to supply the computer_ids in a list.
Is there some kind of nested select type way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `computer_software` table has a column `computer_id` and `software_id` and there is one row per computer and software on that computer -- as I imagine -- then you can count the rows where the computer is either 1/2/5, group by computer_id, having a count equal to 3 (the software appears on all the 3 computers):

```
select software_id
  from computer_software
 where computer_id in (1, 2, 5)
 group by software_id
having count(*) = 3
```

Comment: The better way to do this involves a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse just changed, yeah, not sure why I over-thought it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

John,
I'm a bit rusty but using a subclause with the IN statement should do the trick e.g.

```
select software.id from software
where software.id in 
(
 select computer_software.softwareid from computer_software
 where computer_software.computerid in (1,2,5)
)
```

This won't be the most efficient way to get a result. I guess you would need to use an outer join to increase the efficiency of the query. But if you don't have 100,000 of rows in the computer and software tables it should do the trick as a starting point.

Comment: Isn't this the same as doing: `select software from computer_software where computerid in (1,2,5)`?

Comment: @JohnC - Yes, it is.  No, it won't get what you want (it'll return software on _any_ not all).  Dorje - The optimizer is capable of generating join plans for `IN` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using nested selects, use an inner join on the set of 3 tables.  It is more efficient this way.

```
SELECT software.* FROM software 
  INNER JOIN computer_software ON
     computer_software.software_id = software.id
  INNER JOIN computer ON 
     computer_software.computer_id = computer.id 
  WHERE computer.id IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: This appears to give me the union rather than the intersection.